# Import a list from parent folder

Tags: python, scope, global-variables, modulenotfounderror

```
parent_folder
   | - folder_1
           |- a.py
   | - folder_2
           |- b.py
   | - C.py
```

If I have declared a list in c.py , how can I access it in a.py & b.py.

No matter what I try, I keep running into `ModuleNotFoundError`.

C.py

```
def my_func():
    my_list = ["value_1", "value_2"]
    return my_list
```

Trial 1:

a.py

```
from parent_folder.C import my_func
list_a = my_func()
```

Trial 2:

a.py

```
from parent_folder import C
list_a = C.my_func()
```

Trial 3:

a.py

```
sys.path.append('../parent_folder')
from parent_folder.C import my_func
list_a = my_func()
```

How can I overcome this issue ?

Comment: did you add `__init__.py` files to your module folders? (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for)

Comment: Yes, I had to. An empty __init__.py had to be declared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

`a.py`

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, os.path.join(sys.path[0], '..'))
from C import my_func

list_a = my_func()
```

Comment: Thank you ! This helped solve my issue.